# What to do with duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, exact-duplicates

I was just doing a review queue and saw something I'd never seen before.  A *question* was marked duplicate, and a "late answer" came in on both of the duplicate questions that was the same.  In other words there is now a duplicate *answer* on the duplicate questions.

I know what to do with duplicate questions.  Is there something that's supposed to be done for duplicate answers?

Links to the motivating example:

- [Getting NMEA string from GPS module to your Raspberry PI B+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60106/getting-nmea-string-from-gps-module-to-your-raspberry-pi-b/98920#98920)
- [how to read NMEA 1083 data over USB on Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/65588/how-to-read-nmea-1083-data-over-usb-on-pi/98921#98921)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one closed as a duplicate was closed by me yesterday, after the system flagged the duplicate answers.  The questions aren't exactly the same but near enough, and it seems like a scenario where if anyone wants any details further to that they should ask another question.

The duplicate answers were posted by the same user in the preceeding 24 hours.  There's no rule against this, although since it implies duplicate questions, it doesn't happen often.